# Title shown on browser is different when viewed on a laptop and mobile device

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browser

I have a react application.

When I search for my website online, the title shows as correct, however, when I search the same title but on a mobile device, the title changes.

I have tried to add different titles depending on the screen size however this doesn't work.

Does someone know a direct approach to this or at least some information for why this is happening.

Laptop title: 'Online Services'
Mobile device: 'Therapy Logo'

Answer (score 0):

try using media query, rather than manually setting screen sizes. CSS media has min-width and max-with. Conditionally should render what you are looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).